# Sonarqube 7.9.1 is not starting up with sonar-crowd 2.1.3

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, atlassian-crowd, sonar-plugin

We have upgraded sonarqube from 7.4 to 7.9.1 where we need to upgrade sonar-crowd plugin from 2.1.1 to 2.1.3.

After the upgrade, sonar application is starting up as expected without Crowd config. But while starting up with crowd, it fails at the start up.

Here is the crowd config on sonar properties

```
#-------------------
  # Sonar Crowd Plugin
  #-------------------


  # To first try to authenticate against the external sytem.
  # If the external system is not reachable or if the user is not defined in the external system, the authentication will be performed through the SonarQube internal system.
  sonar.security.realm=Crowd

  # URL of the Crowd server.
  crowd.url=https://mycompany:8443/crowd/


  # Crowd application name.
  # Default is 'sonar'.
  crowd.application=sonar


  # Crowd application password.
  crowd.password=password

  # Crowd group sync
  crowd.groups.sync=true

  # Don't use crowd for sonar account
  sonar.security.localUsers=admin,sonar

  # Don't save passwords incase Crowd is down
  sonar.security.savePassword=false


  # Don't create users, they must come from Crowd
  sonar.authenticator.createUsers=false
```

Is there any dependency plugin for sonar-crowd 2.1.3 ? 
Here is the web log error on latest sonarqube version (7.9.1)

```
2019.11.15 21:19:13 INFO web[][org.sonar.INFO] Security realm: Crowd
2019.11.15 21:19:13 INFO web[][c.a.c.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl] Loading property: 'application.name' : 'sonar'
2019.11.15 21:19:13 INFO web[][c.a.c.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl] Failed to find value for property: application.login.url
2019.11.15 21:19:13 INFO web[][c.a.c.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl] Loading property: 'session.tokenkey' : 'session.tokenkey'
2019.11.15 21:19:13 INFO web[][c.a.c.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl] Loading property: 'session.lastvalidation' : 'session.lastvalidation'
2019.11.15 21:19:13 INFO web[][c.a.c.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl] Loading property: 'session.validationinterval' : '1'
2019.11.15 21:19:13 INFO web[][c.a.c.s.c.ClientPropertiesImpl] Failed to find value for property: cookie.domain
2019.11.15 21:19:13 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Security realm fails to start: Unable to test connection to crowd
at org.sonar.server.user.SecurityRealmFactory.start(SecurityRealmFactory.java:93)
at org.sonar.core.platform.StartableCloseableSafeLifecyleStrategy.start(StartableCloseableSafeLifecyleStrategy.java:40)
at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:135)
at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:90)
at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel4.start(PlatformLevel4.java:545)
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:211)
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel34Containers(Platform.java:185)
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.access$500(Platform.java:46)
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$1.lambda$doRun$0(Platform.java:119)
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$AutoStarterRunnable.runIfNotAborted(Platform.java:371)
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$1.doRun(Platform.java:119)
at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform$AutoStarterRunnable.run(Platform.java:355)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Unable to test connection to crowd
at org.sonar.plugins.crowd.CrowdRealm.init(CrowdRealm.java:106)
at org.sonar.server.user.SecurityRealmFactory.start(SecurityRealmFactory.java:87)
```

Any suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at the of [this](https://github.com/deepy/sonar-crowd/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/crowd/CrowdRealm.java) file.If you think something is changed.

Comment: This means a lot. I've upgraded Java as well for Sonarqube v7.9.1. So I'll take a look on previous java  version configs. Thank you for your tip :)

Answer (score 0):

From the log, I've noticed that it fails with the connection on Crowd.

```
2019.11.15 21:19:13 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Background initialization failed. Stopping SonarQube
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Security realm fails to start: Unable to test connection to crowd
```

Hence whitelisted the Sonarqube APP server IP address and it fixed the issue.